# fscanf() won't store the last line of the file when EOF is reached

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf, stdin

I'm reading a file using stdin and fscanf() but once EOF is reached it doesn't store the word into the array like it does with the rest. all of the words but the last one store into my two dimensional array. Maybe there is better way to do it with fgets() or getchar() but I'm not sure how to do that.

The file I'm reading looks like this

amendment

---

lawsuit

---

justice

and so on (the lines are there because they are on seperate lines and I didn't know of a better way to format it)

my code to read it is this

```
char c;
int column = 0;
int row = 0;

do
{
   word[row][column] = c;
   column++;

while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c)==1 && c != '\n')
{
   word[row][column] = c;
   column++;
}
row++;
column = 0;
}while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c) != EOF);

//here i'm trying to store the last line separately but it doesn't work
while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c)==1)
{
   word[row][column] = c;
   column++;
}
```

Comment: `EOF` occurs before at `}while(fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c) != EOF);`,  The last line has been read by this point.  Why expect a following `fscanf(stdin, "%c", &c)` to return anything but `EOF`?

Comment: My answer from yesterday would really solve your problem. Also you can try modifying it to read directly from files which I can help you doing.

Comment: As there is no output in this code, how have you determined what happened?

Comment: [Example when `getc`(`getchar`) is used](https://ideone.com/tTpov0)